# Typescript regex parse just value not whole match

Tags: angular, typescript

For example '/mentor/33 is url'

I do this with regex:
buildRegex('/mentor/:id');

'/mentor/:id' becomes '/mentor/[^/]'

```
const PATH_PARAM = {
    PREFIX: ':',
    REGEX_IDENTIFIER: '/:[^/]+',
    REGEX_REPLACER: '/[^/]+',
};

private buildRegex(path: string) {
        return this.ensureLeadingSlash(path).replace(
            new RegExp(PATH_PARAM.REGEX_IDENTIFIER, 'g'),
            PATH_PARAM.REGEX_REPLACER
        );
    }
```

How can I just to get back 33, so value from [^/]?

If I use this

```
private matchRegex(routeLink: string, routeRegex: string) {
        const match = routeLink.match(new RegExp(routeRegex, "g"));
        return match?.[0];
    }
```

then I get back /mentor/33 and not 33. I am looking for generic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround the replaced pattern into a group, then reference that group instead of `[0]` after matching. Whether the group should be part of the `PATH_PARAM` or dynamically constructed whenever `buildRegex` is called will depend on your circumstances and what exactly is dynamic.

Because you're only performing the match once, don't use the global flag.

```js
const PATH_PARAM = {
    PREFIX: ':',
    REGEX_IDENTIFIER: '/:[^/]+',
    REGEX_REPLACER: '/[^/]+',
};
const buildRegex = (path) => {
    return path.replace(
        new RegExp(PATH_PARAM.REGEX_IDENTIFIER),
        `(?<pathinfo>${PATH_PARAM.REGEX_REPLACER})`
    );
};
const pattern = buildRegex('/mentor/:id');
const matchRegex = (routeLink, routeRegex) => {
    const match = routeLink.match(routeRegex);
    return match?.groups.pathinfo;
}
console.log(matchRegex('/mentor/33', pattern));
```

If the leading `/` is a problem, note that a `/` *is* included in both your `REGEX_IDENTIFIER` and `REGEX_REPLACER`. Either slice the first character out afterwards, or change the `REGEX_IDENTIFIER` and `REGEX_REPLACER` to remove the slashes, or put the group into the `PATH_PARAM` object itself instead of constructing it dynamically.

```js
const PATH_PARAM = {
    PREFIX: ':',
    REGEX_IDENTIFIER: '/:[^/]+',
    REGEX_REPLACER: '/(?<pathinfo>[^/]+)',
};
const buildRegex = (path) => {
    return path.replace(
        new RegExp(PATH_PARAM.REGEX_IDENTIFIER),
        PATH_PARAM.REGEX_REPLACER
    );
};
const pattern = buildRegex('/mentor/:id');
const matchRegex = (routeLink, routeRegex) => {
    const match = routeLink.match(routeRegex);
    return match?.groups.pathinfo;
}
console.log(matchRegex('/mentor/33', pattern));
```